# Issues with Checkbox list losing Attrubutes on a postback

Tags: c#, checkbox, datalist

I have a Datalist which renders a list of checkboxes and value attributes on each of them, when another control fires a postback the value attribute is lost on each of the checkboxes HELP!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page_load event you might want to check and see if your binding your datalist. If so, you might want to wrap your databinding method with this:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  YourDataBindingMethod();
}
```

With this you will check to make sure that it's only loaded on the first page load. Not each time a control fires a postback.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When you load your Datalist make sure it's only done on the initial PageLoad and not on susequent PostBacks

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
    //databind your datalist
}
```

If that's not the issue, would you care to post some code that could help figure out the problem?

Comment: the datalist is bound inside a repeater control

Comment: how is the repeater populated with data?  Same thing about IsPostBack applies to the repeater